# Can I Sort work with Ruff formatter? (not linter)

Tags: python, formatter, isort, ruff

I am migrating my project to RUFF. The migration was kind of straightforward, but for some reason, ISort rules are not being applied when I do this commands on VSCode: `Format code with > Ruff`

I see this when I have my imports usorted:

[image]

I can click con the `Fast fix` option (`Ctrl+.`. sorry, my VSCode is in Spanish) and it get fixed, but it does not when I do the VSCode Format Code With > Ruff.

In case you want to know, the imports gets fixed when I run `ruff check . --fix`.

Here is my `ruff.toml`

```ini
[lint]
extend-select = [
  "E501", # Add the `line-too-long` rule to the enforced rule set.  # By default, Ruff omits rules that overlap with the use of a formatter
]
ignore = [
  "E712", # (x == True) is allowed.
  "D100", # Docstring allowed rules
  "D105",
  "D107",
  "D203",
  "D213",
]
# Enable Pyflakes (`F`) and a subset of the pycodestyle (`E`)  codes by default.
# Unlike Flake8, Ruff doesn't enable pycodestyle warnings (`W`) or McCabe complexity (`C901`) by default.
# Also add ISort (`I`) rules.
select = ["E4", "E7", "E9", "F", "I"]

# Allow fix for all enabled rules (when `--fix`) is provided. (only safes fixes will be applied)
fixable = ["ALL"]
unfixable = []

# Allow unused variables when underscore-prefixed.
dummy-variable-rgx = "^(_+|(_+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+?))$"

[format]
# Like Black, use double quotes for strings.
quote-style = "double"

# Like Black, indent with spaces, rather than tabs.
indent-style = "space"

# Like Black, respect magic trailing commas.
skip-magic-trailing-comma = false

# Like Black, automatically detect the appropriate line ending.
line-ending = "auto"
```

I am probably doing something wrong, because this iSort fixes used to work with the black formatter. And I have this option selected in VSCode settings.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if `ruff` is executed with the `--fix` flag  in this VS Code command, but I would try to include `fix = true` in the `ruff.toml`.

See https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/settings/#fix for details.